# Convergence of a recursive sequence (logistic differential equation)

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

The logistic differential equation $\dot{x}=x(1-x)$ with $x(0)=x_0>0$ can be discretized with the explicit Euler method, i.e. $x_{k+1}=x_k+hx_k(1-x_k)$. Now we only consider $h\in (0,2)$. How can I show that the fixed point $x^*=1$ is asymptotically stable, that is: there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$||x_0-x^*||<\delta \Rightarrow \lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=x^*.
$$
This is a question from numerical analysis but in this context it is pretty much a pure analysis question. What I've tried is the following:
$$|x_{k+1}-1|=|(x_k-1)-hx_k(x_k-1)|=|x_k-1|\cdot|1-hx_k|\le |x_k-1|(|x_k-1|+|h-1|\cdot |x_k|).
$$
And since $|h-1|<1$, I hoped to achieve some kind of linear convergence, but I don't see how that would work. Is there another way to show convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_{k+1} = f(x_{k})$ and the derivative of $f$ at $x_{0}$ is less than 1 in absolute value then you have stability. This follows from the "contraction principle" i.e.
if $I$ is an interval containing $x_{0}$ where derivative is less than $M < 1$  ( well, we need derivative of $f$ to be continuous as well)
$$|x_{k+1} - x_{0}| = |f(x_{k}) - f(x_{0})| = |f^{'}(y)|*|x_{k} - x_{0}| < M*|x_{k}-x_{0}|$$ where the point y is between $x_{k+1}$ and $x_{0}$.
To be exact, one uses the estimation above and induction.
That is we take $x_{1}$ in the interval $I$ and we get that the distance between $x_{2}$ and $x_{0}$ is less than $M*|x_{1}-x_{0}|$ so $x_{2}$ is in the interval I as well and so on.
One gets $$|x_{k+1}-x_{0}| < M^{k}*|x_{1}-x_{0}|$$
That is $x_{k}$ converges to $x_{0}$ as long as $x_{1}$ is in the interval $I$.

In your case $f(x) = x + hx(1-x)$ so $f^{'}(x) = 1+h-2hx$ and $f^{'}(1)=1-h$